# Weak edges over SPI data lines

Tags: spi, discharge, data-transfer, edge-detection

I am developing a driver for an SPI temperature sensor, and having some trouble with poor quality edges near the end of packet on the data lines.

While I am not experiencing any data loss, I am worried this is evidence of a larger issue; any suggestions on potential simple causes of this problem would be welcome.

[image: Top 2 Traces are MISO (Digital and Analog) Bottom 2 are MOSI]

Temperature Sensor Data Sheet

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1722.pdf

Comment: I would guess that nothing is driving the line during that time period, so the line voltage is only controlled by stray capacitance and input leakage.

Comment: What are the four traces shown? I guess the top two are MOSI/MISO, and one or both of the bottom traces are a chip select? Please add more detail. Please also link the temperature sensor datasheet.

Comment: @TypeIA They are the same traces, MOSI and MISO one is digital render other is the analog signal, top is MISO bottom 2 are MOSI

Comment: You should also have a look at CS (or CS# as appropriate). I think you'll find CS is released at the point where the MOSI/MISO levels start to drift. The levels of MOSI/MISO are not defined when no CS is active and it's normal for them to go high-Z (at which point they are floating, and levels can drift as you see here due to gradual discharge of stray capacitance).

Comment: If something else is not reading this correctly, try adding a 1k-10k pull-up on these lines.

Comment: @rdtsc Unfortunatly it's a mass ordered PCB, I'll have to get the electrical engineers to do a respin of the board if it becomes a major issue

Comment: @TypeIA I think it may be when the clock cycle ends as opposed to when the CS goes low, but it does seem like it's this

Comment: @stmfunk Yep, I think Klas-Kenny's answer and comment are correct, especially that this is normal and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in this table from the datasheet, as soon as the Chip Enable signal goes low, the output of the slave goes into High-Z state until a read operation is initiated.
[image]

Then the output is essentially floating, so the voltage on the line is then determined by some pull up/down if present, or simply by any leakage current on the in/output.

Either way, the voltage on the MISO/MOSI lines really does not matter between the packages sent. So this behavior is both expected, and not an issue.

Comment: I had looked at extended the length of the chip select and that didn't seem to fix the issue. Is it possible the input goes High Z after the end of a clock sequence? I understand it is not an issue, I'd just like to know for future reference

Comment: @stmfunk Yes, it is very likely that the output goes High Z as soon as it has no more data to output, i.e. right after the last bit of a read sequence has been clocked out.

Answer (score 2):

You need pull-up resistors. It's a bad idea to drive CMOS inputs with a floating voltage. The resistors can be relatively large, e.g. 50-500kOhm, so as not to waste power. The signals will then look reasonable. Remember that a scope probe is 10MOhm, so with a 500k pull-up, you'll see voltage 5% smaller than it is without the probe load!